# Windows 10 - Program doesn't work with current .NET framework version

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

I have program (`AutoCAD 2012`) which is not working (it keeps crashing after while) with actual .NET Framework version (4.7x). (Minimal required version is `.NET Framework 4.0`)

For older versions (up to 2010, what I know) there is trick to define what version of .NET Framework has to be used in file `acad.exe.config` placed in program root directory. But these old versions are created for `.NET Framework 3.5` which has could be installed beside `1.x` and `4.x` because backward compatibility.

I'm not aware about possibility to have two different versions of `.NET Framework 4.x` in my system.

Only solution what comes in my mind is emulation of second windows instance of Windows freezed in time for this program only (but this could bring in significant performance loss and file access problems).

Is there some way how to serve older version of `.NET Framework` to this program only?

Thanks for suggestions.

PS: I'm using Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: If you are running the current version of Windows 10 (1909 or 2004) then you have .NET Framework 4.8 installed and it's **impossible** to install .NET Framework 4.7 from any installer.  .NET Framework 4.8 is backwards compatible and is capable of running applications specifically targeted for .NET Framework 4.7.  The fact the application runs, means this is the case on your system, the reason for the crash has to be properly identified for us to help.

Comment: **Is there some way how to serve older version of .NET Framework to this program only?** - This isn't required the application is running, if this was a .NET Framework compatibility problem, the application wouldn't run at all.  **However, it's entirely possible, the application is simply not compatible with Windows 10.**

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, mandatory .NET Framework 4.8 for a current Win10 versions is a new information for me. It's apparent that what I want to achieve is not possible there. (My desire was based on info about propperly running on NET 4.5 (on Win10), but it seems it is not legit (at least for current versions).). Win7 (i have spare lilcense) emulation seems to be only way how to run it on same PC without rebooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update AutoCad to a newer version that complies with Windows 10.

We have a client with Windows 10 and AutoCad and Autodesk kept Version 2012 going for early versions of Windows 10 (now completely out of support) and upgrading AutoCad was the only solution.

There were issues (not just and simply .NET Framework) that require Auto Cad application changes to work with Windows 10 newer versions.

Comment: Thanks for info. I was told that installing an older version of .NET Framework (4.5x) and preventing it from updates was solution (what is not what I want - because security etc.) on one colleague personal PC. It seems legit, because **there is ACAD 2010 properly working on latest Win10** using (forced) .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: You are welcome. The downstream provider (my own ISP) for the client above was dragging their feet on upgrading from Windows 7. So that is done and the client has upgraded Auto Cad.